# Probability density plots from count/value ("binned") data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set which contains 27M samples *per day*.  I can reduce this, using `count()`, to 1500 samples per day, without loss.

When I come to plot, for example, histograms from this, I can use `stat="identity"` to process the count data considerably faster than the original data.

Is there a similar way to process the count data to obtain ridges using `ggridges::geom_density_ridges()`, or similar, to get the probability density without having to process the original data set?

Comment: Yes: According to [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html) you can also do `geom_density_ridges(stat = "identity")`

Comment: @danlooo  That doesn't give a smoothed density function though, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your current set-up is something like this (obviously with far more cases): a data frame containing a large vector of numeric measurements, with at least one grouping variable to specify different ridge lines.

We will stick to 2000 samples rather than 27M samples for demonstration purposes:

```r
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(x = round(c(rnorm(1000, 35, 5), rnorm(1000, 60, 12))),
                 group = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), len = 2000))
```

We can reduce these 2000 observations down to ~200 by using `count`, and plot with `geom_histogram` using `stat = 'identity'`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(x, group) %>%
  count() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y = n, fill = group)) + 
  geom_histogram(stat = 'identity', color = 'black')
```

[image]

But we want to create density ridgelines from these 200 rows of counts rather than the original data. Of course, we could *uncount* them and create a density ridgeline normally, but this would be tremendously inefficient. What we *can* do is use the counts as weights for a density calculation. It seems that `geom_density_ridges` doesn't take a `weight` parameter, but `stat_density` does, and you can tell *it* to use the `density_ridges` geom. This allows us to pass our counts as weights for the density calculation.

```r
library(ggridges)

df %>%
  group_by(x, group) %>%
  count() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, fill = group)) +
  stat_density(aes(weight = n, y = group, height = after_stat(density)), 
               geom = 'density_ridges', position = 'identity')
```

[image]

Note that this should give us the same result as creating a ridgleine from our whole data set before counting, since our 'bins' are unique interval values. If your real data is binning continuous data before counting, you will have a slightly less accurate kernel density estimate when using count data, depending on how 'thin' your bins are.